# Examining program

Tags: python, random, tkinter

At first I thought this would be an easy program where I could learn a lot. But I'm stuck.

How can I ask diffrent questions all after eachother. I have tried some things I came up with but none of those work.

This is the first one, where I use a variable x to re-generate the question. This simply doesn't work.

```
# Laad de database
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='FransSchool', password='RandomPass',host='10.0.0.25', database='Overhoor')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# Maak een grafische interface
gui = Tk()
gui.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

# Verklaringen
def verify():
    overify = antwoord.get()

    if overify == Nederlandsevertaling:
        oentry.delete(0,END)
        x=0
    else:
        oentry.delete(0,END)

x = 0
antwoord = StringVar()
willekeurig = random.randint(0,9)

# Indexeer de database
query = "SELECT FRwoord, NLwoord FROM unite8app1 WHERE id=%s"
cursor.execute(query, (willekeurig,))

while x < 1:
    for (FRwoord, NLwoord) in cursor:
        Fransevertaling = FRwoord
        Nederlandsevertaling = NLwoord
    x+=1
```

And this is the second one which gave me an error. It didn't really came as a surprise that this one didn't work. On button press it tries to recieve a new FR and NLwoord.

```
# Laad de database
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='FransSchool', password='RandomPass', host='10.0.0.25', database='Overhoor')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
# Maak een grafische interface
gui = Tk()
gui.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

# Verklaringen
def verify():
    overify = antwoord.get()

    if overify == Nederlandsevertaling:
        oentry.delete(0,END)
        willekeurig = random.randint(0,9)
        for (FRwoord, NLwoord) in cursor:
            Fransevertaling = FRwoord
            Nederlandsevertaling = NLwoord

    else:
        oentry.delete(0,END)
        #Save the wrong answer aswell as the right answer to print out at the end

antwoord = StringVar()
willekeurig = random.randint(0,9)

# Indexeer de database
query = "SELECT FRwoord, NLwoord FROM unite8app1 WHERE id=%s"
cursor.execute(query, (willekeurig,))

for (FRwoord, NLwoord) in cursor:
        Fransevertaling = FRwoord
        Nederlandsevertaling = NLwoord

# Uiterlijk van het venster

gui.configure(background="white")
gui.title("Overhoorprogramma - Bryan")

# Grafische objecten
style = ttk.Style()

olabel = ttk.Label(gui,text=Fransevertaling,font=("Times", 18), background="white")
olabel.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
oentry = ttk.Entry(gui,textvariable=antwoord, font=("Times", 18))
oentry.grid(row=1, column=0,padx=5, pady=5)
obutton = ttk.Button(gui,text="Suivant", command = verify)
obutton.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
```

At the moment it just clears the entry box on button press. The goal is that everytime an answer has been typed in right it should skip that and if it is typed wrong it has to save it. Either way it has to create a new question what means a new Frword and NLword.

Ideally I am looking for a push in the right direction, the mechanism behind it or a small snippet of code.

Comment: "gave me an error" - what error? Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\Python overhoorprogramma.py", line 20, in verify
    if overify == Nederlandsevertaling:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Nederlandsevertaling' referenced before assignment

Comment: Well, yeah; just look at the function `verify`! That name is not assigned in the function, but you try to use it. You could either make it an argument to the function, or assign it locally before the `if`.

Comment: No, I thought I was using overify (overhoorverify) to get the input from the entry box? Or am I going nuts?

Comment: You get the input; are you trying to check against the *string* `'Nederlandsevertaling'`?

Comment: Yes, first I query Frword and NLword. Later, after the button is pressed I'm trying to re-assign a word to them and change the label to the new FRword.